# Multiple datapoints in series at same point on X axis - Highcharts tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a HighStock graph that occasionally has multiple points at exactly the same location on the X axis. Is it possible to display these in the Tooltip?

Here is an example: http://whatukthinks.org/eu/questions/should-the-united-kingdom-remain-a-member-of-the-eu-or-leave-the-eu/?removed
The 19th October and 25th October both have multiple values, but only one is shown in the Tooltip.

This is my Tooltip setup:

```
tooltip: {
            crosshairs: true,
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function () {
                if( Multiple ) { // Multiple Datapoint graph
                    var s = '<strong>' + this.points[0].point.pollster + '</strong> ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %B %Y', new Date(this.x)) + '<hr class="margin-top-0 margin-bottom-5"/>';
                    s += '<table>';
                    $.each(this.points, function () {
                        s += '<tr><td style="color: ' + this.series.color + '">' + this.series.name + ': </td><td style="text-align: right"><b>';
                        if(this.y == 0.25) {
                            s += '*';
                        } else {
                            s += this.y + '%';
                        }
                        s += '</b></td></tr>';
                    });
                    s += '</table>';
                    return s;
                } else { // Single Datapoint graph
                    var s = '<strong>' + this.point.pollster + '</strong> ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %B %Y', new Date(this.x)) + '<hr class="margin-top-0 margin-bottom-5"/>';
                    s += '<table>';
                    s += '<tr><td style="color: ' + this.series.color + '">' + this.series.name + ': </td><td style="text-align: right"><b>';
                    if(this.y == 0.25) {
                        s += '<strong>*</strong>';
                    } else {
                        s += this.y + '%';
                    }
                    s += '</b></td></tr>';
                    s += '</table>';
                    return s;
                }
            },
            shared: true
        },
```

I'd appreciate any help with this as I'm not sure if it's possible, let alone how to do it!

==============================================================

UPDATE -

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/58Ldnsxs/1/

Using a scatter does let you see a tooltip for each data point, but cannot be used with shared tooltips (noted here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared) which are needed for this...

Comment: Please try to use scatter serie with lineWidth: 2 parameter, instead of line serie.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @SebastianBochan - the formatter broke the tooltip altogether when I changed it to Scatter, but when I removed the formatter and then the graph looked ok. However it still wasn't showing all data in the tooltip.
Do you know that technique should work? If so it must mean something else wrong with my setup... Just wanted to check if you had seen it working before I tear it all down to start again.

Comment: Please recreate your unworking demo (I mean with broken tootlip) on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @SebastianBochan I've created a fiddle and linked it in the Question. Unfortunately I did get a scatter tooltip to work in the Fiddle, but it isn't shared (which I need). The only thing I can think is to use a custom formatter to somehow get all data with the same X value and build a 'fake' shared tooltip. But no idea where to start with that! Any toher ideas? Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Extract x value and use loops on each serie / each point and add a condition where you check if is the same x as current point.